# How to see the code of a TypeScript file instead of the declaration?

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, webstorm

When I try to see the definition of an object or class of my React Native project, the IDE (WebStorm or VSC) brings me to TypeScript's declaration file (d.ts) instead.

How can I make it so I am being brought to the actual code that implements the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible; please vote for [WEB-28729](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28729) and linked tickets to be notified on any progress with this feature